# Assign "Edit" fuctionality to a custom button

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, branding

As we have OOTB "Edit" functionality of SharePoint 2013. I want to assign this functionality to a custom button. How to achieve it.

Comment: Edit what? Edit page, edit item?

Comment: Edit Page functionality

Answer (score 1):

You said you want to trigger the Edit page functionality from a custom button.
I think that the code you have to call really depends on the page type (eg. webpartpage vs wiki page).

By following the instruction [on this blog post](http://spblog.net/post/2012/03/21/How-to-find-correct-javascript-handler-for-OOB-SharePoint-ribbon-button.aspx) (it refers to SP2010, but I'm reasonably sure the same applies to SP2013 as well), you should be able to find out what javascript command is actually called when you click on a ribbon button.

On a wiki page, the javascript that gets called is:

```
CoreInvoke('PageActionClick', this);
```

On a webpartpage, the `<a>` tag id attribute of the ribbon edit page button reads:

```
Ribbon.WebPartPage.Edit.Edit.Menu.Actions.Edit
```

Looking for this string inside the TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML\CMDUI.XML file, you'll see that the command actually called is `webPartPageStartEdit`, which ultimately calls either `window.EnsureCheckoutAndChangeLayoutModeToEdit(this.$1.listId, this.$1.itemId, false);` or `window.ChangeLayoutMode(false, false);` depending on whether the force checkout setting is on or off on the pages library where the page being edited resides.